# New to Flutter and unsure how to proceed with project flutter project, help would be appreciated

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a simple blog for a uni project and unsure how to proceed, i've followed some tutorials to get to where I am and now a bit stuck.

I currently have the home screen with an 'add'(camera icon) button which can  be seen in image one, I then have a second screen (image 2) which allows user to input name, title and image.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

What I want to do is add a save button to the bottom of image 2 which then displays the saved text / image in listview in image 1, and be able to save multiple posts which then stack on top of each other.

The tutorial I was following was using firebase but I would like to do this with JSON, firstly is this possible? and can anyone suggest any methods on how to do this.

code ive written so far:

main.dart

```
import 'package:blog/views/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData.dark(),
  home: HomePage(),
);
}
}
```

create_blog.dart

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io' show File;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CreateBlog extends StatefulWidget {
const CreateBlog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



@override
State<CreateBlog> createState() => _CreateBlogState();
}

class _CreateBlogState extends State<CreateBlog> {
  File? image2;
 final _picker = ImagePicker();
String? authorName, title, desc;

File? selectedImage;

 Future getImage() async {
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: 
ImageSource.gallery);

if (image != null) {
  setState(
    () {
      selectedImage = File(image.path);
    },
    );
  }
}



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
      // Top of Screen Text //

      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Travel',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
        ),
        Text('Blog', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: 
  Colors.green))
      ],
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,

    // Top of Screen widget  //

    actions: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
        // Upload Button //

        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.upload_file,
          ),
        ),
       ),
       ],
       ),

   // Next Widget //

   body: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
    child: Column(
      // Get Image Button //

      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              getImage();
            },

            // Image Return //

            child: selectedImage != null
                ? Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 
 16),
                    height: 150,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        child:
                            Image.file(selectedImage!, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  )

                // Hold Image Box //

                : Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo,
                        color: Colors.black))),

        // Text Boxes Code //

        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  authorName = val;
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Date'),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  title = val;
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Blog Body'),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  desc = val;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

home.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 import 'create_blog.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

//  Main Home Page //

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Travel',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
            Text('Blog',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.green))
          ]),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
    ),
    body: Container(),
    floatingActionButton: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CreateBlog()));
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo))
          ]),
     ));
  }
 }
```

So far the code works great and I am able to upload an image to the second screen from local storage, just unsure how to save it.

I started writing some JSON code from another tutorial but unsure if this is the right way to go

client.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class FileManager {
static FileManager? _instance;

FileManager._internal() {
_instance = this;
}

factory FileManager() => _instance ?? FileManager._internal();

Future<String> get _directoryPath async {
Directory? directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
return directory!.path;
}

Future<File> get _file async {
final path = await _directoryPath;
return File('$path/blog.txt');
}

Future<String> readTextFile() async {
String fileContent = 'blog text';

File file = await _file;

if (await file.exists()) {
  try {
    fileContent = await file.readAsString();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
return fileContent;
}
}
```

Sorry about length of post and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend this course: [Udemy: Flutter](https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps/). You need to understand the basics of flutter.